# Sort, bucket and apply function to DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
              'Score': [2, 6, np.nan, 3, 4],
              'Value 1': [10, 30, 20, 5, 15],
              'Value 2': [400, 250, 100, 300, 150]})

         Name   Score   Value 1 Value 2
0          A    2.0      10      400
1          B    6.0      30      250
2          C    NaN      20      100
3          D    3.0       5      300
4          E    4.0      15      150
```

I would like to bucket this data frame into: [Top Quartile, Second Quartile, Third Quartile, Bottom Quartile, No Rating] based on the sorting of 'Score' and then calculate, say the average of the values that fall in the corresponding bucket from 'Value 1' and 'Value 2'. So, the NaN from Score should fall in the No Rating bucket and 30 from 'Value 1' and 250 from 'Value 2' should fall in Top Quartile, as the score of 6 is highest (30 and 250 the average of a single number is itself).

Answer (score 1):

You can apply qcut as follows;

```
df['bucket'] = pd.qcut(df['Score'], 4, ['q1','q2','q3','q4'])
df.groupby('bucket')[['Value 1','Value 2']].mean()
```

Normally, it will exclude NaN, thus I change the bucket column to str ,or you can apply fillna to specify the value to NaN.

```
df['bucket'] = df['bucket'].astype(str)
df.groupby('bucket')[['Value 1','Value 2']].mean()
```